# how wrap list items by <a> tag in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this list in the HTML page and I want to create dynamic navbar menu based on number of section in an HTML page

```
 <ul id="navbar__list">
    ....
 </ul>
```

And when I write this code in a js file

```
const LIST = document.querySelector("#navbar__list");
const SECTION = document.querySelectorAll("section");
SECTION.forEach((sec) => {
  let id_name = sec.getAttribute("id");
  let atr_data = sec.getAttribute("data-nav");
  const NAV_LIST_ITEMS = document.createElement("li");
  NAV_LIST_ITEMS.textContent = atr_data;
  const NAV_LIST_ANCHOR = document.createElement("a");
  NAV_LIST_ANCHOR.setAttribute("href", "#" + id_name);
  const full_list_link = NAV_LIST_ANCHOR.appendChild(NAV_LIST_ITEMS);
  LIST.appendChild(full_list_link);
});
```

the result became like this

```
<ul id="navbar__list">
    <li>Section 1</li>
    <li>Section 2</li>
    <li>Section 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want final code like this

```
<ul id="navbar__list">
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><li>Section 1</li></a>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><li>Section 2</li></a>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><li>Section 3</li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't use rage case for local variables.

Comment: Why don't you use template literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure you desire is not possible as it is not valid HTML. `<ul>` and `<ol>` elements can only have `<li>` elements as their direct descendants. Consider placing the link inside the list item.

```js
const LIST = document.querySelector("#navbar__list");
const SECTION = document.querySelectorAll("section");
SECTION.forEach((sec) => {
  let id_name = sec.getAttribute("id");
  let atr_data = sec.getAttribute("data-nav");
  const NAV_LIST_ITEMS = document.createElement("li");
  const NAV_LIST_ANCHOR = document.createElement("a");
  NAV_LIST_ANCHOR.setAttribute("href", "#" + id_name);
  NAV_LIST_ANCHOR.textContent = atr_data;
  NAV_LIST_ITEMS.appendChild(NAV_LIST_ANCHOR);
  LIST.appendChild(NAV_LIST_ITEM);
});
```

This should generate (based on your own example) the following code:

```html
<ul id="navbar__list">
  <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Section 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Section 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Footnote:** the convention in JavaScript is to use `camelCase`  for variables and `UPPERCASE` for constants:

```
const WHITE = '#ffffff'; // Immutable string.
const navListItem = document.createElement("li"); // Is an object with mutable properties.
```